# Custom plugin definition not loading

Tags: 9, plugins

I'm trying to create my own plugin type in Drupal 9 but it's not finding my test definition and I can't figure out why.

Here's my services.yaml:

```
services:
  plugin.manager.reaction:
    class: Drupal\nm_events\ReactionManager
    parent: default_plugin_manager
```

Here's ReactionManager.php:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\nm_events;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager;

/**
 * Defines the reaction plugin manager.
 */
class ReactionManager extends DefaultPluginManager {

  /**
   * Constructs a ReactionManager object.
   *
   * @param \Traversable $namespaces
   *   An object that implements \Traversable which contains the root paths
   *   keyed by the corresponding namespace to look for plugin implementations.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface $cache_backend
   *   Cache backend instance to use.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler
   *   The module handler.
   */
  public function __construct(\Traversable $namespaces, CacheBackendInterface $cache_backend, ModuleHandlerInterface $module_h
andler) {
    parent::__construct('Plugin/Reaction', $namespaces, $module_handler, 'Drupal\nm_events\ReactionInterface', 'Drupal\nm_even
ts\ReactionAnnotation');
    $this->setCacheBackend($cache_backend, 'reaction_plugins');
    $this->alterInfo('reaction_info');
  }

}
```

Here's my Annotation class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\nm_events;

use Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin;

/**
 * Declare a class for event reactions.
 *
 * Plugin Namespace: Plugin\Reaction.
 *
 * @see plugin_api
 *
 * @Annotation
 */
class ReactionAnnotation extends Plugin {
  /**
   * The plugin ID.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  public $id;

  /**
   * The human-readable title of the plugin.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation
   *
   * @ingroup plugin_translatable
   */
  public $title;

}
```

And here's my Test plugin (in src/Plugin/Reaction/Test.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\nm_events\Plugin\Reaction;

use Drupal\nm_events\ReactionInterface;

/**
 * Test reaction.
 *
 * @Reaction(
 *   id = "test",
 *   title = @Translation("Reaction for testing reactions")
 * )
 */
class Test implements ReactionInterface {
  public function processEvent($event, $entity) {
    var_export($event->title->value);
  }
}
```

But when I try to get the definitions:

```
$ drush cr
 [success] Cache rebuild complete.
$ drush php
Psy Shell v0.11.17 (PHP 8.0.15 — cli) by Justin Hileman
New/Mode base (Drupal 9.5.8)

> $p = $container->get('plugin.manager.reaction')
= Drupal\nm_events\ReactionManager {#2893}

> $p->getDefinitions();
= []
```

Edit: Here's the interface definition:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\nm_events;

use Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginInspectionInterface;

/**
 * Defines an interface for a Reaction plugin.
 *
 * @see plugin_api
 */
interface ReactionInterface extends PluginInspectionInterface {
  public function processEvent($event, $entity);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played a little bit and changed the structure slightly, but finally made it work. Here's my example:

Final structure:

```
├── pm_test.info.yml
├── pm_test.services.yml
└── src
    ├── Annotation
    │   └── ReactionAnnotation.php
    └── Plugin
        ├── Reaction
        │   └── Test.php
        ├── ReactionInterface.php
        └── ReactionManager.php
```

services.yml looks like this:

```
services:
  plugin.manager.reaction:
    class: Drupal\pm_test\Plugin\ReactionManager
    parent: default_plugin_manager
```

Annotation class(`src/Annotation/ReactionAnnotation.php`)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\pm_test\Annotation;

use Drupal\Component\Annotation\Plugin;

/**
 * Declare a class for event reactions.
 *
 * Plugin Namespace: Plugin\Reaction.
 *
 * @see plugin_api
 *
 * @Annotation
 */
class ReactionAnnotation extends Plugin {

  /**
   * The plugin ID.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  public $id;

  /**
   * The human-readable label of the plugin.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation
   *
   * @ingroup plugin_translatable
   */
  public $label;

}
```

The ReactionInterface (`src/Plugin/ReactionInterface.php`)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\pm_test\Plugin;

use Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginInspectionInterface;

/**
 * Defines an interface for a Reaction plugin.
 *
 * @see plugin_api
 */
interface ReactionInterface extends PluginInspectionInterface {

  public function processEvent($event, $entity);

}
```

The ReactionManager(`src/Plugin/ReactionManager.php`)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\pm_test\Plugin;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager;

/**
 * Defines the reaction plugin manager.
 */
class ReactionManager extends DefaultPluginManager {

  /**
   * Constructs a ReactionManager object.
   *
   * @param \Traversable $namespaces
   *   An object that implements \Traversable which contains the root paths
   *   keyed by the corresponding namespace to look for plugin implementations.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface $cache_backend
   *   Cache backend instance to use.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler
   *   The module handler.
   */
  public function __construct(
    \Traversable $namespaces,
    CacheBackendInterface $cache_backend,
    ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler,
  ) {
    parent::__construct(
      'Plugin/Reaction',
      $namespaces,
      $module_handler,
      '\Drupal\pm_test\Plugin\ReactionInterface',
      '\Drupal\pm_test\Annotation\ReactionAnnotation'
    );

    $this->alterInfo('reaction_info');
    $this->setCacheBackend($cache_backend, 'reaction_info_plugins');
  }

}
```

And finally the Test(`/src/Plugin/Reaction/Test.php`):

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\pm_test\Plugin\Reaction;

use Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginBase;
use Drupal\pm_test\Annotation\ReactionAnnotation;
use Drupal\pm_test\Plugin\ReactionInterface;

/**
 * Test reaction.
 *
 * @ReactionAnnotation(
 *   id = "test",
 *   title = @Translation("Reaction for testing reactions")
 * )
 */
class Test extends PluginBase implements ReactionInterface {
  public function processEvent($event, $entity) {
    var_export($event->title->value);
  }

}
```

At the end, I checked the same way with drush and here's the result:

```
Psy Shell v0.11.18 (PHP 8.0.24 — cli) by Justin Hileman
Drush Site-Install (Drupal 9.5.9)
> $p = $container->get('plugin.manager.reaction');
= Drupal\pm_test\Plugin\ReactionManager {#7435}

> $p->getDefinitions();
= [
    "test" => [
      "id" => "test",
      "title" => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup {#7452},
      "class" => "Drupal\pm_test\Plugin\Reaction\Test",
      "provider" => "pm_test",
    ],
  ]
```

In my opinion the biggest issue with your code was the Annotation. Instead of using

```
 * @Reaction(
 *   id = "test",
 *   title = @Translation("Reaction for testing reactions")
 * )
```

it should have been

```
 * @ReactionAnnotation(
 *   id = "test",
 *   title = @Translation("Reaction for testing reactions")
 * )
```

after the name of the annotation class. I hope this helps

Comment: Heh) Almost in same time)). Funny, what is a chance of such event could happen.

Comment: Thanks to you both, I switched @Reaction to ReactionAnnotation and it worked, but I'll probably apply the other refactoring too. I'm not sure who to give the bounty to now!

Comment: You may see the entire refactored structure here, including the Test class extension of the PluginBase, so it's fully functional

Comment: @VladMoyseenko - indeed, funny case :D

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- A. Adjust Test class with correct annotation id
- B. Rewrite your code
  to follow common approaches with plugin definition.

A. The `Test.php` reaction plugin uses wrong annotation name. Instead of `@Reaction` there sholud be `@ReactionAnnotation`.

B. Code Refactor.
There are couple of issues with your code:

1. Rename and move ReactionAnnotation.php from `nm_events/src/ReactionAnnotation.php` into `nm_events/src/Annotation/Reaction.php` and adjust namespace to `Drupal\nm_events\Annotation` and class name to `Reaction`
2. Change annotation name in `ReactionManager.php` from `Drupal\nm_events\ReactionAnnotation` to `Drupal\nm_events\Annotation\Reaction`
3. Change annotation id within `Test.php` from `@ReactionAnnotation` to `@Reaction`

After this adjustments `$p = $container->get('plugin.manager.reaction')->getDifitions()` should show your test plugin.

However.
When you try to create plugin instance: `$test = $container->get('plugin.manager.reaction')->createInstance('test', [])`

You will get fatal error `Test contains 2 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods`. To fix it you need extend it with `Drupal\Core\Plugin\PluginBase` class.

Now instance could be created.

Note.
I would recommend to take a look how other core modules deal with plugins, there are lot's of useful classes out of the box in Drupal.
Here is example: [ImageEffectManager.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/tree/11.x/core/modules/image/src/ImageEffectManager.php).
And maybe you also need plugin collection similar to: [ImageEffectPluginCollection](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/11.x/core/modules/image/src/Entity/ImageStyle.php#L402)

To save time you can use `drush generate plugin:manager` command and create all stuff (including service, annotation, interface, manager, test plugin, plugin interface) using provided wizard.